# Preventing all checkboxes from being set to true/false when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

I'm working in Knockout and I'm trying to get specific information when a specific checkbox is checked.  However, what's happening is every checkbox is being selected/deselected when I click on one.  My question is, how do I prevent that from happening and make it to where only the check box I select/deselect is checked/unchecked?

**JS**
I've simplified this to show just the code I'm working with.

```
export class Model{
    isSelected: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    constructor(){
        this.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
    }
    selectStuff = () => {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: stuffToLoopThrough">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkBox" data-bind="checked: $root.isSelected, click: $root.selectStuff" />Send Stuff

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkBox" data-bind="checked: $root.isSelected, click: $root.selectStuff" />Send Stuff

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkBox" data-bind="checked: $root.isSelected, click: $root.selectStuff" />Send Stuff
</div>
```

So what's happening here is, if I were to click on one of the three check boxes, every checkbox would be selected, I want just the check box I selected to be checked.  How do I make that happen?  Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: They're all bound to the same variable. You need an observable in each item of `stuffToLoopThrough` to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting multiple values selected or just one? If you just want 1 use a radio not a checkbox.

Either way, check out the `checkedValue` binding which allows you to store results in a variable:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

```
var stuffToLoopThrough = Model[];
var selectedValue = ko.observable();

    export class Model{
    isSelected: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    constructor(){
        this.uniqueValueOrId= ko.observable();
        this.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
    }
    selectStuff = () => {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then the html

```
<div data-bind="foreach: stuffToLoopThrough">
    <input type="radio"
           class="radio" 
           name="checkBox" 
           data-bind="checked:  isSelected, 
           checkedValue: $root.uniqueValueOrId, 
           click: $root.selectStuff"> Send Stuff
</div>
```

notice I am not using the $root for the checked...